# if I put accept all 0.0.0.0/0 means this server is totally open for any ip?

Tags: linux, iptables

```
ACCEPT     all  --  0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0
```

is this means allow all ip from all port?

but I still can not visit the server except I go through the allowed ip address

and if I put this line in any line, did I make this server totally open for any connection?

the full iptable list is below

```
Chain INPUT (policy ACCEPT)
target     prot opt source               destination  
ACCEPT     all  --  0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0       
ACCEPT     all  --  116.211.25.89        0.0.0.0/0           
ACCEPT     all  --  222.215.136.8        0.0.0.0/0           
ACCEPT     all  --  125.82.87.21         0.0.0.0/0           
ACCEPT     all  --  127.0.0.1            127.0.0.1           
ACCEPT     tcp  --  61.172.251.109       0.0.0.0/0           tcp spt:8080 
ACCEPT     tcp  --  61.172.254.123       0.0.0.0/0           tcp spt:8080 
ACCEPT     tcp  --  61.129.44.191        0.0.0.0/0           
ACCEPT     tcp  --  61.129.44.128        0.0.0.0/0           
ACCEPT     tcp  --  61.172.251.109       0.0.0.0/0           tcp spt:8080 
ACCEPT     tcp  --  61.172.254.123       0.0.0.0/0           tcp spt:8080 
ACCEPT     icmp --  0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0           icmp type 0 
ACCEPT     icmp --  0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0           icmp type 8 
ACCEPT     tcp  --  0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0           tcp spt:53 
ACCEPT     udp  --  0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0           udp spt:53 
ACCEPT     udp  --  0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0           udp spt:123 
ACCEPT     udp  --  0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0           udp dpt:123 
ACCEPT     tcp  --  0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0           tcp spt:20 
ACCEPT     tcp  --  0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0           tcp spt:21 
ACCEPT     tcp  --  0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0           tcp spt:80 
ACCEPT     tcp  --  0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0           tcp spt:88 
ACCEPT     tcp  --  0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0           tcp spt:8000 
ACCEPT     tcp  --  0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0           tcp spt:8080 
ACCEPT     tcp  --  0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0           tcp spt:8888 
ACCEPT     tcp  --  0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0           tcp spt:873 
ACCEPT     tcp  --  0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0           tcp spt:6969 
ACCEPT     tcp  --  0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0           tcp spt:6900 
ACCEPT     tcp  --  61.172.241.98        0.0.0.0/0           
ACCEPT     tcp  --  61.172.247.98        0.0.0.0/0           
ACCEPT     tcp  --  61.172.247.100       0.0.0.0/0           
ACCEPT     tcp  --  61.152.122.33        0.0.0.0/0           
ACCEPT     tcp  --  61.152.110.130       0.0.0.0/0           
ACCEPT     tcp  --  210.51.28.220        0.0.0.0/0           
ACCEPT     tcp  --  210.51.28.120        0.0.0.0/0           
ACCEPT     tcp  --  61.172.241.120       0.0.0.0/0           
ACCEPT     tcp  --  211.147.0.85         0.0.0.0/0           
ACCEPT     tcp  --  211.147.0.114        0.0.0.0/0           
ACCEPT     tcp  --  222.73.61.249        0.0.0.0/0           
ACCEPT     tcp  --  222.73.61.250        0.0.0.0/0           
ACCEPT     tcp  --  222.73.61.251        0.0.0.0/0           
ACCEPT     tcp  --  210.51.31.11         0.0.0.0/0           tcp dpt:38422 
ACCEPT     tcp  --  210.51.31.12         0.0.0.0/0           tcp dpt:38422 
ACCEPT     tcp  --  61.172.254.123       0.0.0.0/0           tcp spt:8080 
ACCEPT     tcp  --  61.172.251.109       0.0.0.0/0           tcp spt:8080 
ACCEPT     tcp  --  61.172.247.85        0.0.0.0/0           
ACCEPT     tcp  --  222.73.12.248        0.0.0.0/0           
ACCEPT     tcp  --  61.172.254.184       0.0.0.0/0           
ACCEPT     tcp  --  61.172.254.78        0.0.0.0/0           
ACCEPT     tcp  --  61.172.254.243       0.0.0.0/0           
ACCEPT     tcp  --  61.152.97.115        0.0.0.0/0           
ACCEPT     tcp  --  221.231.128.206      0.0.0.0/0           
ACCEPT     tcp  --  221.231.130.199      0.0.0.0/0           
ACCEPT     udp  --  172.0.0.0/8          0.0.0.0/0           udp dpt:161 
ACCEPT     udp  --  10.0.0.0/8           0.0.0.0/0           udp dpt:161 
ACCEPT     udp  --  192.168.0.0/16       0.0.0.0/0           udp dpt:161 
ACCEPT     udp  --  61.172.252.58        0.0.0.0/0           udp dpt:161 
ACCEPT     udp  --  61.183.13.201        0.0.0.0/0           udp dpt:161 
ACCEPT     udp  --  222.73.2.11          0.0.0.0/0           udp dpt:161 
ACCEPT     udp  --  221.208.157.158      0.0.0.0/0           udp dpt:161 
ACCEPT     udp  --  218.30.74.250        0.0.0.0/0           udp dpt:161 
ACCEPT     udp  --  202.102.54.234       0.0.0.0/0           udp dpt:161 
ACCEPT     udp  --  125.64.2.115         0.0.0.0/0           udp dpt:161 
ACCEPT     udp  --  222.73.23.23         0.0.0.0/0           udp dpt:161 
ACCEPT     udp  --  210.51.33.97         0.0.0.0/0           udp dpt:161 
ACCEPT     udp  --  210.51.33.98         0.0.0.0/0           udp dpt:161 
ACCEPT     udp  --  222.73.11.112        0.0.0.0/0           udp dpt:161 
ACCEPT     udp  --  222.73.11.111        0.0.0.0/0           udp dpt:161 
ACCEPT     udp  --  222.73.11.89         0.0.0.0/0           udp spt:38514 
DROP       tcp  --  0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0           tcp dpt:38423 
REJECT     tcp  --  0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0           reject-with tcp-reset 
DROP       all  --  0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0           

Chain FORWARD (policy ACCEPT)
target     prot opt source               destination         
DROP       all  --  0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0           

Chain OUTPUT (policy ACCEPT)
target     prot opt source               destination         
ACCEPT     udp  --  0.0.0.0/0            222.73.11.89        udp dpt:38514
```

Comment: The normal listing doesn't include the interface. Add `-v`.

Comment: Please post the output of `iptables-save`. `iptables -L` hides some rules, making troubleshooting patently difficult.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

> is this means allow all ip from all port?

Not necessarily. Add '-v' option(iptables -nv -L) to show all/out interface.

```
4060K  498M ACCEPT     all  --  lo     *       0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0
```

Comment: thanks so much ! I just saw the "lo" in -v mode. I was so confused :D,thanks again !

Comment: why even have an option to not list interfaces? stupid.

Answer (score 2):

If you don't want IPtables why don't you disable them. 
`iptables -F` should do the trick

Else provide more details like the port and IP you are trying to connect to and your IP

Comment: Don't forget you might want to reset the policy of each chain, before you do this, or you merit the unmerciful banhammer of your own ssh connection.